# How to update series based on other pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to update data based on other pandas dataframe because I just gather better data, here's the example of dataset

Heres my Data

```
No  Country    Language    Capital
1   Indonesia  Bahasa      Jakarta
2   Malaysia   Bahasa      Kuala Lumpur
3   Brunei     Bahasa      Bandar Seri Begawan
4   Nigeria    English     Abuja
```

My second dataframe

```
Nation     Capital City
Malaysia   Lagos
Nigeria    Putrajaya
```

What I want is

```
No  Country    Language    Capital
1   Indonesia  Bahasa      Jakarta
2   Malaysia   Bahasa      Putrajaya
3   Brunei     Bahasa      Bandar Seri Begawan
4   Nigeria    English     Lagos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new `Series` with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), which create for non exist `Nation`s `NaN`s, whcih are replaced by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df2.set_index('Nation')['Capital City']
df1['Capital'] = df1['Country'].map(s).fillna(df1['Capital'])
print (df1)
   No    Country Language              Capital
0   1  Indonesia   Bahasa              Jakarta
1   2   Malaysia   Bahasa                Lagos
2   3     Brunei   Bahasa  Bandar Seri Begawan
3   4    Nigeria  English            Putrajaya
```

Or slowier solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df1['Capital'] = df1['Country'].replace(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

First create a series from your new mapping:

```
s = df2.set_index('Nation')['Capital City']
```

Then use [`pd.Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) to update your series in-place:

```
df1['Capital'].update(df1['Country'].map(s))
```