# Can I find alternative `.loc` alternative for replace function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Previously, I'm asking [How to update series based on other pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504354/how-to-update-series-based-on-other-pandas-dataframe), and there exist 3 answers, but 3 of them give caveats, usually I ignoring this, but this is for production purpose, so I'cant. Here's the answer and the caveat:

1

```
s = df2.set_index('Nation')['Capital City']
df1['Capital'] = df1['Country'].map(s).fillna(df1['Capital'])
```

caveat

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

2

```
df1['Capital'] = df1['Country'].replace(s)
```

caveat

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

3

```
s = df2.set_index('Nation')['Capital City']
df1['Capital'].update(df1['Country'].map(s))
```

caveat

```
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How to reduce the caveat

Comment: Problem is in code above?

Comment: The code is working, but caveat on jupyter notebook, in my previous feature engineering deployment, usually caveat on jupyter notebook give problem on production

Comment: This kind of error is very confused, because problem is one line before. Obviously if some filtering, then need `df = df1[df1['col'] == 10].copy()`.

Comment: Ok, this is works. you can post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is obviously in one line before in filtering.

`Solution` is add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) like:

```
df1 = df[df['col'] == 10].copy()
```

`Explanation`:

If you modify values in `df1` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that `Pandas` does warning.